# How to use XmlWriter to write non-well formed xml

Tags: c#, xml, streamwriter, xmlwriter

First off, I don't like doing this. This isn't my choice.

I need to write information to an xml document. The simpleContent of the xml may contain &'s. I want these to written to the file as just `&`, not `&amp;`

How do I do this? I'm guessing that it includes a StreamWriter and something like:

```
 private void SaveCaption_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (saveCaptionDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveCaptionDialog.FileName, null))
            {
                using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer))
                {
                    xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                    xmlWriter.Indentation = 4;
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
                    xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("tt");
                    ...
                    xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                    xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
                }
            }
            //streamWriter do your thing
        }

    }
```

Comment: Write the whole thing to a string, then `Replace("&amp;", "&")` on it?

Comment: Why isn't it your choice and why would you do this AND retain XML as your format of choice? You won't be able to parse it!

Comment: @SpaceBison - My guess? Because we don't always get to write code to interface with standards compliant systems.

Comment: @antiduh I recognise the reality of your statement, however I find it a struggle to want to have XML that cannot be used by another system, without some kind of 'fixing' of it....

Comment: @SpaceBison The limelight video player we are using requires an xml doc to show captions. All ways of encoding '&' come out as their plain text equivalent (e.g. "&amp;")

Comment: @MichaelKay - That's a pretty heavy handed thing to do. This is most certainly concerning XML and XML-related technologies. The fact that it's not 100% proper encoding is irrelevant. This asker is making a perfectly reasonable request in an imperfect world, and certainly deserves the attention of developers familiar with XML. Your contribution is counter-productive.

Comment: Yep, OK, it was a bit heavy-handed. But there are so many people struggling trying to read bad XML, seeing someone ask for help in creating bad XML is just so depressing it makes one angry.

Comment: @MichaelKay - I feel your pain too, but you're trying to punish the wrong person. It's not his fault this app (limelite) doesn't parse xml correctly. You have to work within the constraints you're given. What else would you have him do, assume the text contains english sentences and transliterate '&' to 'and' to avoid the whole problem? FWIW, i put a 'with much power comes great responsibility' warning in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please only do this if you absolutely must; this is not standards compliant XML.

*Only you can prevent XML fires.*

Use the `WriteRaw()` method:

```
        XmlWriter writer;

        writer = XmlWriter.Create( @"C:\users\account\desktop\test.xml" );

        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        writer.WriteStartElement( "TestElement" );
        writer.WriteRaw( "Hello & goodbye" );
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();

        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
```

Which generates the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><TestElement>Hello & goodbye</TestElement>
```